# Time difference in php gives me strange number of hours

Tags: php, time, datetime-format

My code is

```
   $start_time= time();
   echo "<BR><BR>";
   echo "start: ".date("G:i:s",$start_time);echo "<BR>";
   echo "now: ".date("G:i:s",time());echo "<BR>";
   echo "difference: ".date("G:i:s",time()-$start_time);echo "<BR>";

   echo "<BR><BR>";
   echo time()-$start_time;
   echo "<BR><BR>";
```

and the output is

```
start: 12:03:41
now: 12:06:04
difference: 10:02:23


143
```

Any idea why number of hours is not 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly setting a time zone for you script?

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: Could you explain why this helped? :-)

Comment: I don't know for sure but my guess is that date() converts to localtime and time() is returning the time in UTC - the PHP docs aren't clear on what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use unix timestamp when calculating date differences.

See below

```
$start_time= date("U", time());
sleep(5); //stops execution for 5 seconds
$endtime = date("U",time());
echo date("G:i:s",$endtime - $start_time); //Outputs 0:00:05
```

or something like this for actual date / time differences

```
 $start_time= date("U", strtotime("11/11/11 12:53"));
 $endtime = date("U",strtotime("11/11/11 12:59"));
 echo date("G:i:s",$endtime - $start_time);
```

Outputs `0:06:00` 6 minutes

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work for me because of different time zone? The fix for me was  adding `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
` to my current code.

Answer (score 1):

Difference should just be time() - $start_time to give the number of seconds it takes to run the script.  If you pass it to date, then it will give the date 143 seconds after the Unix Epoch.  Make the date format 'Y/m/d G:i:s' to see exactly what's going on there.